# Setting a textarea's line-height to a percentage equal to the same height as a li element in the background

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm having troubles when it comes to setting a textarea's line-height. I want it to always be the same height as the `li` elements in the background, because when you resize the screen the text goes over the lines and into new rows which doesn't look good at all. I've been trying to think of a way of solving this but I keep drawing blank.. The `li` has a `height` of `5%` and I need the `line-height` of the `textarea` to also be `5%`, but I need that percentage to be based on the `ul`'s `height` and not the `content-wrapper`'s. Is it possible to achieve this in some way? See below for details.

Take a look at this image (each row is a `li`):

[image: explanatory picture]

It has this structure:

```
<main class="full-height">
    <div id="top-bar">
        <button id="all-notes" class="btn brown-btn hide">Alla anteckningar</button>
        <button id="add-note" class="btn brown-btn">Ny</button>
        <input type="submit" form="note-text" value="Klar" id="done-btn" class="btn brown-btn hide">
        <button id="edit" class="btn brown-btn hide">Ändra</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content-wrapper" class="full-height">
        <div class="vertical-stripes"></div>
        <div class="vertical-stripes"></div>
        <ul id="note-block" class="reset">
            <li>
                <span>Idag</span>
                <span class="date"><?php include('datetime.php'); ?></span>
                <span><?php echo date('H:i'); ?></span>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <form id="note-text" method="post" action="../includes/notepages/savenote.php">
            <textarea name="textarea" id="notes-area">Text goes here</textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
</main>
```

The CSS for the textarea covering everything as well as the `li`s which makes up the text rows.

```
ul#note-block {
    height: 90%;
    border: $thin-grey;
    @include smoothEdges($bottomLeft: 10px, $bottomRight: 10px);
    z-index: 1;

    li {
        height: 5%;
        border-bottom: $thin-grey;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: $notes-yellow;
    }
}

textarea#notes-area {
    position: absolute;
    top: 17%;
    left: 12%;
    width: 86%;
    height: 72%;
    line-height: 43px; //This can't be a fixed px height, needs to be 5% like the li above
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    resize: none;
    overflow: auto;
    background: none;
    font-family: notesworthy;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When CSS height is specified in percentages, it's a percentage of the [height of a containing element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height). Thus elements with a 5% height declaration will still be different heights because of the height of their parents.

Try one of the other relative units for declaring height such as `rem` or `vh`. [`1rem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Font-relative_lengths) is the same height as `html` element's font size, while [`1vh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) is 1/100th the height of the viewport. Both of these units will be relative to the visitor's browser, but the same no matter what element you're styling.